# Difference between Power System Contingency analysis and Power Network Loading study

Tags: power-supply, power, high-voltage, transmission-line, power-engineering

I was reading through some research papers on **Power system contingency analysis** but it seems like the researcher is talking more about **network loading**. I searched on the internet about the difference but I just couldn't get something that can make me understand.

Comment: Um, which research papers exactly? Links would be helpful.

Comment: Plenty of things have titles that don't relate. Surely the detail is important but, if maybe you had bought a book on the basis of the title only to find that watership down was about rabbits and not some WW2 sea battle, you won't be the first. Do you actually have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For power distribution there are a lot of networks for redundant delivery but risk and load factors must be analyzed for capacity load leveling and service due to failure.

Now graphical methods are used to illustrate the severity of risk and exposure to power availability in case of component failures.

> In contrast to **contingency severity** information, **power system
>   element vulnerability** describes ... in terms of their
>   **post-contingency load factors.**
>   Hence,the primary focus here is on the violated element itself, with the different categories of visualizations showing sequentially more detail about
>   the contingencies which cause violations on the element.
>   three different categories are presented: overview, middle-level, and detail in this [report](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar_url?url=http://pserc.wisc.edu/ecow/get/publicatio/2004public/cavisualizationpapermarch02ieee.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0lvW_C3U_-NH8PqarIRI9z1hnYDg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ved=0ahUKEwi7pNGZx8nPAhXBQyYKHfLQBNwQgAMIISgBMAA)

[image]